Dolphin safely remove: how to achieve the same result fully unmount the drive in the terminal
If I connect an external HDD to my PC via USB
sudo lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT

would show the HDD and its partitions (and an empty mountpoint):
sdd
  sdd1  ext4
  sdd2  ntfs

I could mount them using
sudo mount /dev/sdd1 /media/username/FIRSTHDD
sudo mount /dev/sdd2 /media/username/SECONDHDD

They would be visible and navigable in file explorer's left side panel (Dolphin).
I could also unmount them using
sudo umount /dev/sdd1
sudo umount /dev/sdd2

The mount point from the lsblk output would become empty yet again.
However the partitions would still be visible in the file explorer.
If I mount the partitions again and then right click them in file explorer and click Safely Remove, they would disappear from both file explorer and lsblk output. The only way to see and mount them yet again would be to unplug and plug back the USB.
I'd like to know what command the Safely Remove option in Dolphin is using that it makes the partitions to disappear from both the left side panel and the lsblk output? Is there a way I could achieve that result myself in the terminal?  Because the umount command doesn't seem to fully remove the partitions from being visible by the system.
